# CommandError: App 'accounts' does not have migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

when i run python manage.py makemigrations accounts and python manage.py migrate accounts, it does not create a migrations folder and even when i run python manage.py migrate it migrates all apps except accounts. The app has a pycache folder though

I expected it to create a migrations folder

Comment: Is your app listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have 'accounts' listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the *settings.py* file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort it out:

I forgot to change `is_Active` to `True` in my model to enable users' login; the initial problem was users not being able to log in.